# MongoDB Atlas on GCP : Is there a way to restrict MongoDB Atlas to accept connection requests from only Compute instances running in my project

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, mongodb-atlas

I am evaluating MongoDB Atlas on GCP. We use managed instance groups in GCP with auto-scaling; so new instances get created on the fly based on demand and we cannot foresee the IPs of these new instances. Hence we cannot use the "whitelist IP" approach to control access. Is there any way to restrict MongoDB Atlas to accept connection requests from only Compute instances running in my project?